# How to do a negative join ("except") in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML:

```
<Products xmlns="urn:shop.fruit">
  <!-- documento XML para a pergunta 5 -->
  <Stock>
    <product name="banana" quant="2000" un="kg"/>
    <product name="aple" quant="3000" un="kg"/>
    <product name="orange" quant="3500" un="kg"/>
    <product name="melon" quant="1000" un="kg"/>
  </Stock>
  <Prices>
    <product name="aple" un="€">1.2</produto>
    <product name="melon" un="€">1.5</produto>
  </Prices>
</Products >
```

I want the XPath that gives me as result the names of all the products that are in the stock tag except the ones inside the Prices tag.
The result that I want is: name="banana"; name="orange".
I have tried this XPath: `/Produtos/Stock/produto/@nome except /Produtos/Preços/produto/@nome`
but it seems that the except operator is not accepted.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

The `except` operator is only available in XPath 2.0, but you can accomplish what you want in XPath 1.0 (and XPath 2.0) without `except`...

**First, within the context of the environment in which the XPath will be evaluated, define a namespace prefix for the `urn:shop.fruit` namespace:**

```
u=urn:shop.fruit
```

**Then, the following XPath**

```
/u:Products/u:Stock/u:product[not(@name = /u:Products/u:Prices/u:product/@name)]/@name
```

**Will return**

```
banana
orange
```

**as requested.**

### Update:

Here is a shorter solution suggested by @Tomalak:

```
/u:Products/u:Stock/u:product/@name[not(. = /u:Products/u:Prices/u:product/@name)]
```

@Tomalak and @JLRishe also offered the helpful explanation that these solutions work because in XPath, `X = Y` is a set operation that operates like an INNER JOIN.  @JLRishe further notes that `X != Y` is a set operation too but is specifically not equivalent to `not(X = Y)`.

Comment: @Tomalak `!=` is also a set operation that works like an INNER JOIN. That's precisely why `X != Y` is not the same as `not(X = Y)`.

Comment: @JLRishe Of course you are right. Sadly I can't edit my comment anymore, so I delete it.